# How can I properly import the environment from running a subcommand in Perl?

Tags: perl, environment

In importing the environment from a subcommand, I want to add all environment variables exported from a bash script to a hash. When `program` gets run, it will set up some variables and export them. I'd like to save those variables in the Perl script for later. However I don't want to take the bash functions defined in the subcommand. Currently, I have a block like:

```
foreach (`program; env`)
{
    next if /^\(\)/;
    my ($a, $b) = split("=", $_);
    if( /^(\w+)=(.*)$/ ) {
        $hash{$1} = $2;    
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? I'm not sure if matching the initial () is safe. Bonus points for handling newlines in environment variables, which I'm just closing my eyes for right now.

Comment: I have to admit that I have no idea how the title of your question relates to its body. The word "alias", e.g., doesn't even show up.

Comment: Echoing Manni, you need to fix that title. Right now, it does not mean anything to me.

Comment: Agreed. That title is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I think I get it now. You want to run an external program which changes its environment and you want to get your hands on that environment. I'm afraid that won't work.

Comment: The biggest proble mis determining the difference between things that were exported as environment variables and functions that the shell exports(with export -f)

Comment: @qedi I did not even know about `export -f`. It seems like those names always start with `()`. I updated my code to skip those.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I import environment settings into my Perl program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590937/how-do-i-import-environment-settings-into-my-perl-program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the environment variables after `program` has executed are not same as the environment passed to it (which you can find in `%ENV` as explained in [jeje's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200849/how-can-i-determine-the-difference-between-an-alias-and-a-function/1200878#1200878).

I am by no means knowledgeable about bash, so I am only going to address the part of the question about parsing the output of `env`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use autodie qw( open close );

$ENV{WACKO} = "test\nstring\nwith\nnewlines\n\n";

my %SUBENV;

open my $env_h, '-|', 'env';

my $var;

while ( my $line = <$env_h> ) {
    chomp $line;
    if ( my ($this_var, $this_val) = $line =~ /^([^=]+)=(.+)$/ ) {
        if ( $this_val =~ /^\Q()\E/ ) {
            $var = q{};
            next;
        }
        $var = $this_var;
        $SUBENV{ $var } = $this_val;
    }
    elsif ( $var ) {
        $SUBENV{ $var } .= "\n$line";
    }
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%SUBENV;
```

Answer (score 5):

What you want is there:  [Shell-EnvImporter](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Shell-EnvImporter/)

An example:

```
  use Shell::EnvImporter;

  # Import environment variables exported from a shell script
  my $sourcer  = Shell::EnvImporter->new(
                   file => $filename,
                 );


  my $result = $sourcer->run() or die "Run failed: $@";
```

Comment: Ok, I copy/paste from the doc

Comment: Brilliant! But I think you better delete your other answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fine for getting all of the environment variables.

```
for(`program; env`){
  if( /^([^=]+)=(.*)$/ ) {
    $hash{$1} = $2;    
  }
}
```

If you want to start with a clean slate this might work better.

```
for(`env -i bash -c "program; env"`){
  next if /\(\)/;
  if( /^([^=]+)=(.*)$/ ) {
    $hash{$1} = $2;    
  }
}
```

`env -i` makes it's subcommand start off with a clean slate.

It calls bash with the `-c` argument, and the commands to run. We need to do that because otherwise the second `env` wouldn't get the environment variables from the program.